# SSAS downtime when restoring cube

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas

I am experiencing downtime when restoring a SSAS cube. This made me wonder if SSAS does an in-place restore or if it restores in parrallel and then replaces the live cube? I can't seem to find any answer in the MSDN docs.

Does anyone know how a SSAS restore works and if SSAS will reject connections to a cube while a restore is in process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the cube is ultimately file-based, acquiring a writelock on it in order to overwrite during a restore would prevent all access to the file, including queries to the cube.

[This article has a lot of details on what happens during the backup/restore process.](http://sqlcat.com/sqlcat/b/technicalnotes/archive/2008/03/16/analysis-services-synchronization-best-practices.aspx) Here's the relevant part:

> Note that when you are restoring the database on the target server, a
>   read lock is first initiated and then released for validation, a write
>   lock is initiated if the database exists, restoration of files occurs,
>   the write lock is released, and then the read lock is released. This
>   mechanism of locks ensures the integrity of the database as its being
>   restored. At the same time, this also means that the database cannot
>   be queried during the restore.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for this article, it confirmed my suspicions as well as hightlight an approach I have been considering taking (doing a backup and then rename).

Answer (score 0):

Please use synchronize option if you dont want any downtime for users which allows simultanious access to SSAS databases.